# element invisible but still clickable on safari browser

Tags: html, wordpress, css, safari

i have a sidebar menu drawer made based on bootstrap

it run well and showing on IE 11, Edge, Chrome and Firefox

but it invisible and still clickable on safari for windows (version 5.1.7) also on a iPhone device. i don't really know why this is happen

according to the screenshot, the sidebar menu is showing on the taskbar thumbnails, but in browser window, it doesn't show

[image]

css code for showing :

```
 .site-header-menu.toggled-on {
  margin-top: 23%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 85%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

css code for hiding :

```
.site-header-menu {
  margin-top: 31% !important;
  height: 100%;
  width: 85%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: -500px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

You can also check by yourself on the website itself [Here](https://www.heatinggreen.com/)

please kindly share your knowledge on this. any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Please look at: [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

is the `display: none` or `width: 0`. In any of these cases, you shouldn't have this problem. But if you set `visibility: hidden` you are likely to have this problem and if in that case, you one of the options above

i don't think using `right: -500px` is the best option. instead, change the width. Do, `width: 0%`

Comment: i used `right: -500px` for slide the menu element to the right, if i use `width: 0%` the element will disappear on the middle of the page

Comment: what i need here, is to show the sidebar menu drawer that i made, on safari. because the bug is, the element is invisible

Comment: yeah. If you use the `width: 0` or `display: none` to hide the div and use `width: 80%` or `display: block` to show the div, it should work just fine

Comment: i've tried your solution, unfortunately the problem still persist

Answer (score 0):

Just give

> pointer-events: none;

for invisible element so that clickable not working on this.

Comment: what i need here, is to show the sidebar menu drawer that i made, on safari. because the bug is, the element is invisible